# Uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular

проблема с Angular 5 material: установил angular material, все нормально работает до момента, пока не импортирую какой-то компонент, после этого в консоле браузера ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function и куча варнингов. В чем может быть проблема?

```
Файл material.module.ts:

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';

@NgModule({
imports: [MatMenuModule],
exports: [MatMenuModule]
})

export class MaterialModule{}

app.module.ts:
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ApiDataComponent } from './api-data/api-data.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { ApiService } from './api.service'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ApiDataComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [ApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Приветствую! Не удалось решить проблему?

Comment: Думал может вы подкинете идею, но уже разобрался сам) У меня была проблема в версиях `npm`-пакетов самого роутера и сборщика проекта (у меня это `@reils/webpacker`) пришлось откатывать до минорных